# NRI having NRE, NRO and domestic bank acount

Tags: taxes, income-tax, india, capital-gains-tax

I am an Indian citizen with NRI (NonResident Indian) status, and I have
an NRE account, an NRO account, as well as an ordinary bank account in India.
I need to know

1. How to treat my investments done under Demat account attached to my domestic bank account.
2. How to treat mutual fund (MF) investments done through the domestic bank account.
3. How to redeem MF schemes.
4. Let me know tax implication on my earlier foreign currency remittance to my own domestic bank account. Of course, now I am remitting to my NRE account only.
5. How I pay my LIC premium since my existing SB account has been converted to an NRO account.

Comment: There are lots of questions here, but the first thing you need to get resolved is that as an NRI, you are not supposed to hold ordinary (domestic) bank accounts in India; they have to be converted to NRO accounts.

Answer (score 1):

> as well as an ordinary bank account in India

NRI can't hold normal savings account. Have this converted to NRO.

> How to treat my investments done under Demat account attached to my domestic bank account.

You would need separate Demat Accounts. For existing shares before you became NRI, NONPINS. Another PINS after you became NRI and traded in shares. Read the question [Indian Demat account](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/47052/indian-demat-account)

> How to treat mutual fund (MF) investments done through the domestic bank account.

Gains are taxable in India similar to resident Indian.

> How to redeem MF schemes.

Depends on how you purchased them. Paper if paper based, via Bank portal if electronic. Credits are typically directly paid into Bank Account.

> Let me know tax implication on my earlier foreign currency remittance to my own domestic bank account

None.

> How I pay my LIC premium since my existing SB account has been converted to an NRO account.

In the same way as you were doing in the past.